# Plugin de Splashcreen (cordova) e ícones não funcionam no Crosswalk

Tags: java, android, apache-cordova, crosswalk

Estou usando [esse módulo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-android-crosswalk) que adiciona um wrapper do Crosswalk num projeto Cordova automaticamente.

**Obs**: Ele exige que a "platform" seja a android@3.6.3.

Ok, daí eu dou o comando para fazer o Wrap do Crosswalk no projeto e tudo ocorre bem.

Ele faz build normalmente com o plugin de *dialogs* e outros. No entanto quando eu instalo o plugin de Splashscreen e tento dar run, acontece um erro:

```
-pre-compile:
     [echo] Set jars path to: /home/rop/Projetos/Pray/cordovaa2/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes.jar:/home/rop/Projetos/Pray/cordovaa2/platforms/android/CordovaLib/xwalk_core_library/ant-build/classes.jar:/home/rop/Projetos/Pray/cordovaa2/platforms/android/CordovaLib/xwalk_core_library/libs/xwalk_core_library_java_app_part.jar:/home/rop/Projetos/Pray/cordovaa2/platforms/android/CordovaLib/xwalk_core_library/libs/xwalk_core_library_java_library_part.jar

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 5 source files to /home/rop/Projetos/Pray/cordovaa2/platforms/android/ant-build/classes
    [javac] warning: /home/rop/Projetos/Pray/cordovaa2/platforms/android/CordovaLib/xwalk_core_library/libs/xwalk_core_library_java_app_part.jar(org/xwalk/core/XWalkView.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
    [javac] It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
    [javac] /home/rop/Projetos/Pray/cordovaa2/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/splashscreen/SplashScreen.java:232: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method canGoBack()
    [javac] location: class org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView
    [javac]         if (webView.canGoBack()) {
    [javac]                    ^
    [javac] 1 error
    [javac] 1 warning

BUILD FAILED
/opt/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/android-sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 4 seconds

/home/rop/Projetos/Pray/cordovaa2/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: ant with args: debug,-f,/home/rop/Projetos/Pray/cordovaa2/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: /home/rop/Projetos/Pray/cordovaa2/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

Minha estrutura de pastas:

[image: Estrutura de pastas]

Meu config.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>appName</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <platform name="android">

        <splash src="res/android/screen/res-long-port-hdpi/default.png" densitit="port-hdpi"/>
        <splash src="res/android/screen/res-long-port-ldpi/default.png" densitit="port-ldpi"/>
        <splash src="res/android/screen/res-long-port-mdpi/default.png" densitit="port-mdpi"/>
        <splash src="res/android/screen/res-long-port-xhdpi/default.png" densitit="port-xhdpi"/>

        <icon src="res/android/icon/drawable-ldpi/appicon/png" density="ldpi" />
        <icon src="res/android/icon/drawable-mdpi/appicon.png" density="mdpi" />
        <icon src="res/android/icon/drawable-hdpi/appicon.png" density="hdpi" />
        <icon src="res/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi/appicon.png" density="xhdpi" />

    </platform>
</widget>
```

[image: XML]

**PS**: Além disso, nem os ícones funcionam, apesar de não dependerem de Plugins... Sempre que dou run, o app se instala com o ícone default do Cordova.

Comment: Você deu o comando do `crosswalk` antes ou depois de adicionar o Plugin da SplashScreen?

Comment: Quais instruções você está usando para compilar? Qual é  versão do compilador?

Comment: @VictorStafusa, uso o Cordova 4.2.0, Android 5.1 API 22. Uso o 'cordova run android' mas da esse erro eu tiver instalado o plugin de splashscreen (sem ele compila normal).

Comment: Se você der um `javac -version`, o que aparece?

Comment: @VictorStafusa 1.6.0_34

Comment: Dei uma pesquisada nos Códigos da linha 232 do arquivo `/splashscreen/SplashScreen.java` e percebi que ele realmente chama uma função `canGoBack` de uma variável do WebView, como o `crosswalk` altera a aplicação para utilizar o `Chromium webview` acredito que ela não tenha esta função ou implementação. Por isso verifique se ao efetuar o comando do `crosswalk` de converter o projeto você ta tem o plugin instalado.

Comment: @PedroHenrique, eu tenho o plugin na pasta Plugins do projeto. Eu estou usando esse módulo pra facilitar o processo de instalar o Crosswalk https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-android-crosswalk. Ele exige a plataforma android na versão 3.6.3.

Comment: @ropbla9 Consegui reproduzir o erro, vou fazer alguns testes e já te informo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como comentado o problema não é apresentado antes de utilizar o `cordova-android-crosswalk`, isso ocorre devido a versão da biblioteca do `Cordova`, o Crosswalk exige a versão 3.6.3, está versão possui algumas diferenças entre uma classe chamada `CordovaWebView.java`, basicamente ela não implementa todas as funções da classe e separa entre mais arquivos. Não vou me aprofundar muito já que o problema aqui é sobre Cordova e não Java.

Mas bem para solucionar o problema é bem simples, vamos apenas editar um arquivo.

Dentro da pasta principal do seu projeto procure o arquivo `platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView.java`

Abra este arquivo e logo após a declaração da classe `CordovaWebView` (linha 80) cole o seguinte código.

```
    public boolean canGoBack() {
        return super.getNavigationHistory().canGoBack();
    }
```

Depois basta tentar novamente dar o comando de build do seu projeto.

Comment: funcionou. Muito obrigado! Tem como te dar uma recompensa?

Comment: Não sei amigo, tente sinalizar a pergunta e verificar com um administrador ou pergunte para um usuário mais experiente. Da próxima vez procure apenas gratificar e marcar a resposta certa depois de verificar se a mesma resolve seu problema. No mais fico feliz que tenha resolvido seu problema, qualquer hora me avise se o crosswalk realmente deixa os aplicativos de Cordova mais rapido.

Comment: compila mas ainda assim a splashscreen nao aparece. Tudo permanece configurado como na pergunta...

Comment: Vou editar a resposta com a configuração da splash, os ícones também não funcionam ainda?

Comment: eu já consegui man!

Comment: quando eu fui atualizar a versão do Java veio junto várias features na barra do ubuntu: Java8 Mission control, Java8 console, java8 visualVM etc.. Como eu faço para remover?

Comment: @ropbla9 Então você conseguiu executar seu aplicativo sem problemas ou ainda possui dificuldades? Sobre a barra do Ubuntu veja se este link ajuda http://askubuntu.com/questions/71240/how-to-remove-icons-shortcuts-from-unity-menu não utilizo muito Ubuntu por isso não posso te ajudar em relação a isso.

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com a [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file):

> J2SE 8 = 52
>   J2SE 7 = 51
>   J2SE 6.0 = 50
>   J2SE 5.0 = 49
>   JDK 1.4 = 48
>   JDK 1.3 = 47
>   JDK 1.2 = 46
>   JDK 1.1 = 45

Nos seus erros aparece isso:

> ```
> warning: /home/rop/Projetos/Pray/cordovaa2/platforms/android/CordovaLib/xwalk_core_library/libs/xwalk_core_library_java_app_part.jar(org/xwalk/core/XWalkView.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
> ```

Vamos dar uma atenção especial a isso:

> (org/xwalk/core/XWalkView.class): major version 51 is newer than 50, the highest major version supported by this compiler.

Você informou que o seu compilador (ao tentar usar `javac -version`) é o 1.6.0_34, ou seja, *major version 50*. Entretanto, aparentemente a classe `org.xwalk.core.XWalkView` foi compilada com o Java 7 (*major version 51*) e como consequência disso o compilador do Java 6 não é capaz de entendê-la ou de utilizá-la.

Para resolver isso, eu vejo três possíveis alternativas (não mutuamente excludentes):

- Fazer o upgrade do seu compilador para Java o 7 ou Java 8. No entanto, é preciso tomar cuidado para ter certeza que o android aceitará as classes resultantes. Se essas classes usarem o *try-with-resources*, então elas só funcionarão no Android KitKat (API level 19, Android 4.4) ou superior ([Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20480090/does-android-support-jdk-6-or-7)). Além disso, o Android ainda não aceita Java 8, mas você pode usar como uma das opções ao invocar o compilador, `-target 1.6` ou `-target 1.7`.
- Recompilar estas classes com o compilador do Java 6, se você tiver [o código-fonte](https://github.com/crosswalk-project).
- Usar alguma ferramenta que faça o downgrade da classe do Java 7 (ou 8) para o Java 6. A ferramenta para este propósito mais conhecida é o [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda).

---

Quanto aos ícones, observe isso no seu XML:

```xml
<icon src="res/android/icon/drawable-ldpi/appicon/png" density="ldpi" />
```

Ao invés de `appicon/png`, deveria ser `appicon.png`. No entanto, não sei se é só isso que está errado ou se há mais alguma coisa.

Para saber mais detalhes, seria bom você descrever melhor a sua estrutura de pastas, em especial o que há dentro do `res`.

---

E algumas dicas sobre a sua pergunta:

- Você se esqueceu de colocar as tags [android](/questions/tagged/android) e [java](/questions/tagged/java). Como resultado, pouca gente viu a sua questão e ela só me chamou a atenção por causa da recompensa ativa. Não se esqueça das tags da próxima vez!
- Não coloque código em formato de imagens, pois fica difícil de ler (pois o navegador redimensiona a imagem) e além disso o texto não é selecionável. Eu só percebi o erro do seu ícone ao reescrever todo o XML quando estava editando a sua pergunta.

Comment: instalei o Java 7 de acordo come essa resposta aqui http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263556/installing-java-7-on-ubuntu. Nao funcionou; mesmo erro

Comment: @ropbla9 Esse link aí mostra como instalar uma máquina virtual Java 7 (JRE). O que você precisa é de um compilador Java 7 (JDK). Não adianta você ter uma JVM do Java 7 ou Java 8, se o seu compilador ainda é Java 6, pois neste caso você (obviamente) só vai conseguir compilar programas até o Java 6.

Comment: to sem tempo agora. Amanha vou tentar instalar o compilador e testar denovo, mas ja marquei tua resposta

Comment: tentei suas 3 soluções e o problema persiste. Instalei até o Java JKD 8 e nada

Comment: eu tenho o plugin de splash na pasta Plugins do projeto. Eu estou usando esse módulo pra facilitar o processo de instalar o Crosswalk https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-android-crosswalk. Ele exige a plataforma android na versão 3.6.3. Se eu não instalar o cordova nem a plataforma 3.6.3 (normal) nada da errado.